# embedding .jar file to webpage/website

Tags: java, object, jar, applet, embed

I have a client who has a java based game which he wants to make available online (at the moment it is desktop version which he had to install). He asked me whether I can embed it into a webpage. After trying for several days still no joy. Can you please point me to the right direction. It have fives jar files(executable jar file) and a folder called lib which has five more jar files. Now I don't know whether it is possible to embed the game using applet/object tag. Can you please point me what to look at when dealing with these jar files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..at the moment it is desktop version which he had to install..

Launch it from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It might be necessary to digitally sign the Jars (what does the app. do?).

Note that a 'desktop application' would typically be coded using a `JFrame`, whereas the equivalent top-level container for embedding is a `JApplet`.  A frame cannot simply be embedded in a web page.

As the rest of the problems mentioned, you'll need to be a lot more specific about what you tried and the results of those attempts, or find some psychic helpers.